# Why is Excel Calculating UDFs in an Unexpected Order?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

Excel is Calculating a UDF in an unexpected order.  Keep in mind, for the remainder of this discussion, that I have Calculation set to Manual.

I have the following minimal UDF defined in a module:

```
Function MyFunction(r As Range, i As Integer) As Integer
    Debug.Print Application.ThisCell.Address
    MyFunction = i
End Function
```

Note the parameter `r`, defined as a Range, is never used.  The function just prints the Cell in which it appears to the Immediate window and returns the Integer passed to it.

First, I show the positive case, where Excel behaves as expected.  Here's the spreadsheet that uses this function.  Note that column C merely shows what's in Column A:

[image]

Here, `1` was entered into cell A3 and then the spreadsheet was saved, causing Excel to perform the calculation.  You would expect the UDF to be run first for cell A5 (as it is clearly dependent on A3) and then for cell A7 (as it is clearly dependent on cell A5).  And this is exactly what happens.  Here's the contents of the Immediate window:

```
$A$5
$A$7
```

Now for the negative case.  Look at this slight revision to the spreadsheet:

[image]

Instead of the 2nd argument to `MyFunction` being a cell reference, it is now just an integer (2 and 3, respectively).  Note that the formula in A5 *still* refers to A3 and that the formula in A7 *still* refers to A5.  Again, `1` is entered into A3 and the spreadsheet is saved and again Excel performs the calculation.  But this time the order of execution of the UDF `MyFunction` is reversed.  Now the contents of the Immediate window are:

```
$A$7
$A$5
```

This is the reverse of what I expected.  What is happening here?

Comment: Is this a curiosity question, or do you have a specific use case where the calculation order is important?

Comment: Do you have multithreaded calculation enabled? Does the call order change back to what you expect if you declare your function as `(r As Long, i As Integer)`? (I would assume it does, because currently the function depends on the cell object itself, not its value, and the cell object itself is not going anywhere.)

Comment: @BigBen I believe in conformance with Stackoverflow standards, I have boiled my problem down to the simplest case to illustrate the issue I am having.  In my actual application, the VBA code consists of many VBA UDFs, each relying on VBA classes.  That significantly larger project is experiencing this issue, where the execution of one UDF that is dependent on another invocation of the same UDF in another cell is happening in the reverse order (or at least, in an order I didn't expect and can't explain).

Comment: Exactly how are you triggering the calculation?  If you press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9 to trigger a full recalculation does the Immediate window output seem correct?

Comment: @GSerg Multi-threaded calculation is enabled.  You were correct, changing `r` from `Range` to `Long` resolved the issue, at least in this minimal instance of the issue I was having.  I'll apply your suggestion (resolution?) to my actual app and see what happens.

Comment: @TimWilliams In an attempt to answer your question, I reverted the code back to define `r` as a `Range`.  But then I was unable to reproduce the problem.  Even after closing and restarting Excel.

Comment: @mbmast to reproduce the problem do this: go in A5 and press Enter, go in A7 and press Enter, then go to A3 and change the value. I try Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9 as Tim Williams suggests and the result is $A$7 $A$5. Also with GSerg suggestion if do that i describe (A5...enter, A7...enter, A3 change value) THE FIRST ONLY TIME get  $A$7 $A$5 $A$7 double execution of $A$7

Comment: @mbmast When there is no dependency on the value, there is likely no stable order of calculation either, so it's to be expected that you cannot reproduce.

Comment: [Here's a good discussion of calculation order](https://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm)

Comment: @mbmast Somewhat related, because you mentioned you have a lot of UDFs, check out the [FastExcelUDFs](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FastExcelUDFs) repository. If you really have a lot of UDFs (thousands) then this will help with speed issues.